# Creating a Python list comprehension with an if and break

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, list-comprehension

Is it possible to turn this code into a list comprehension?

```
for i in userInput:
    if i in wordsTask:
        a = i
        break
```

I know how to convert part of it:

```
[i for i in userInput if i in wordsTask]
```

But I don't know how to add the break, and the documentation hasn't been much help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
a = next(i for i in userInput if i in wordsTask)
```

To break it down somewhat:

```
[i for i in userInput if i in wordsTask]
```

Will produce a list. What you want is the first item in the list. One way to do this is with the next function:

```
next([i for i in userInput if i in wordsTask])
```

Next returns the next item from an iterator. In the case of iterable like a list, it ends up taking the first item.

But there is no reason to actually build the list, so we can use a generator expression instead:

```
a = next(i for i in userInput if i in wordsTask)
```

Also, note that if the generator expression is empty, this will result in an exception: `StopIteration`. You may want to handle that situation. Or you can add a default

```
a = next((i for i in userInput if i in wordsTask), 42)
```

Comment: Very nice! And very subtle--given the OP's asking for help learning list comprehensions, you probably ought to explain what's going on here.

Comment: note that if `len(userInput) == 0` could be `True` then one should provide a default via the second argument of `next`: `a = next( (generator expression), default )`

Comment: make it a little more verbose please.

Comment: Good but you forgot that: when a generator expression is not the only argument to a function, it is required that it has parenthesis around it.

Comment: @DanD. ah! I make that mistake every time

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I was off researching the next function. It looks _very_ useful. Thanks a lot for the replies and help.

Comment: @julio.alegria, no I chose it because it was six times nine

Comment: `next([i for i in userInput if i in wordsTask])` raises `TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator` for me. Did this change since 2012?

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge, no I just did it wrong ten years ago.