# Creating a Python list comprehension with an if and break with nested for loops

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nested-loops, break

I noticed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014058/creating-a-python-list-comprehension-with-an-if-and-break) answer that the code

```
for i in userInput:
    if i in wordsTask:
        a = i
        break
```

can be written as a list comprehension in the following way:

```
next([i for i in userInput if i in wordsTask])
```

I have a similar problem which is that I would like to write the following (simplified from original problem) code in terms of a list comprehension:

```
 for i in xrange(N):
     point = Point(long_list[i],lat_list[i])
     for feature in feature_list:
         polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
         if polygon.contains(point):
             new_list.append(feature['properties'])
             break
```

I expect each `point` to be associated with a single polygon from the feature list. Hence, once a polygon that contains the point is found, `break` is used to move on to the next point. Therefore, `new_list` will have exactly `N` elements.

I wrote it as a list comprehension as follows:

```
new_list = [feature['properties'] for i in xrange(1000) for feature in feature_list if shape(feature['geometry']).contains(Point(long_list[i],lat_list[i])]
```

Of course, this doesn't take into account the `break` in the `if` statement, and therefore takes significantly longer than using nested for loops. Using the advice from the above-linked post (which I probably don't fully understand), I did

```
new_list2 = next(feature['properties'] for i in xrange(1000) for feature in feature_list if shape(feature['geometry']).contains(Point(long_list[i],lat_list[i]))
```

However, `new_list2` has much fewer than N elements (in my case, `N=1000` and `new_list2` had only 5 elements)

Question 1: Is it even worth doing this as a list comprehension? The only reason is that I read that list comprehensions are usually a bit faster than nested for loops. With 2 million data points, every second counts.

Question 2: If so, how would I go about incorporating the `break` statement in a list comprehension?

Question 3: What was the error going on with using `next` in the way I was doing?

Thank you so much for your time and kind help.

Comment: `next()` is used to take the first list item, and effectively throw the rest of the list away.  Ideally, Python only creates the items you ask for, and if you never try to look at the rest of the list, it's never calculated. What about `new_list3 = [next(feature['properties'] for feature in feature_list if shape(feature['geometry']).contains(Point(long_list[i], lat_list[i]))) for i in xrange(1000)]` ?

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions are not necessarily faster than a `for` loop.  If you have a pattern like:

```
some_var = []
for ...:
    if ...:
        some_var.append(some_other_var)
```

then yes, the list comprehension is faster than the bunch of `.append()`s.  You have extenuating circumstances, however.  For one thing, it is actually a generator expression in the case of `next(...)` because it doesn't have the `[` and `]` around it.

- You aren't actually creating a list (and therefore not using `.append()`).  You are merely getting one value.
- Your generator calls `Point(long_list[i], lat_list[i])` once for each feature for each `i` in `xrange(N)`, whereas the loop calls it only once for each `i`.
- and, of course, your generator expression doesn't work.

Why doesn't your generator expression work?  Because it finds only the first value overall.  The loop, on the other hand, finds the first value *for each `i`*.  You see the difference?  The generator expression breaks out of both loops, but the `for` loop breaks out of only the inner one.

---

If you want a slight improvement in performance, use `itertools.izip()` (or just `zip()` in Python 3):

```
from itertools import izip

for long, lat in izip(long_list, lat_list):
    point = Point(long, lat)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I understand now that the `next` causes a break out of both loops, which is why it doesn't work. I also understand how izip might improve performance. However, if you look at my original code, I am doing precisely an .append() (`new_list.append(feature['properties']); break`). Does your original statement about extenuating circumstances still hold?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that complex list comprehensions or generator expressions are that much faster than nested loops if they're running the same algorithm (e.g. visiting the same number of values). To get a definitive answer you should probably try to implement a solution both ways and test to see which is faster for your real data.

As for how to short-circuit the inner loop but not the outer one, you'll need to put the `next` call inside the main list comprehension, with a separate generator expression inside of it:

```
new_list = [next(feature['properties'] for feature in feature_list
                                       if shape(feature['shape']).contains(Point(long, lat)))
            for long, lat in zip(long_list, lat_list)]
```

I've changed up one other thing: Rather than indexing `long_list` and `lat_list` with indexes from a `range` I'm using `zip` to iterate over them in parallel.

Note that if creating the `Point` objects over and over ends up taking too much time, you can streamline that part of the code by adding in another nested generator expression that creates the points and lets you bind them to a (reusable) name:

```
new_list = [next(feature['properties'] for feature in feature_list
                                       if shape(feature['shape']).contains(point))
            for point in (Point(long, lat) for long, lat in zip(long_list, lat_list))]
```