# list comprehension with if and break

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Is it possible to do this trick with a list comprehension:

```
queries = """watch movie online, sport news, movie poster, course of events, movie in this summer, python course, serials about sports, watch movie about training course"""
keywords = ['movie','course']
```

all good with this method

```
for x in queries.split(','):
    for y in keywords:
        if y in x:
            print(x)
            break
```

when i used a list comprehension like this:

```
r = [print(x) for x in queries.split(',') for y in keywords if y in x]
```

I have 2-time result with a match on two 2 keywords `watch movie about training course`

When i use method in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9014075/8843645) i had an error `'list' object is not an iterator`

Comment: don't use a list comprehension here. List comprehensions are for *creating lists* not for printing

Comment: `print(x)` just a simple, i can use a `[lst.append(x)]` in this construction. Then i can use a set(lst) to do distinct values. maybe exist a method with one line construction?

Comment: No. Do **not** use `lst.append` in a list-comprehension, list comprehensions **are for creating lists** not for side-effects.

Comment: You could do something like `matches = [x for x in queries.split(',') if any(y in x for y in keywords)]` then `for match in matches: print(match)`

Comment: In general, do not think about a list-comprehension as a "single-line for loop". That isn't it's purpose. It is a functional construct used to create lists, to combine mapping/filtering behavior in a nice, readable format. Don't use side-effects in your list comprehension, and if you don't need a list at the end, don't use a list comprehension.

Comment: dont understand why side-effects is bad for list comprehensions? but your `any`  works

Comment: Because it is inefficient, you create an empty lists of `None` objects when you could simply just use a for-loop. Again, list-comprehensions are a construct borrowed from functional programming languages (Haskell). If you use them, you should stick to functional paradigm, i.e. no side effects. If you *want* a if-statement and a break-statement (non-functional, imperative constructs) then just use the very pythonic if-statements and break-statement. Mixing the two styles usually leads to something worse, at the very least, something unclear to understand

Comment: thank, for explain. but it just a test, I can delete a `print(x)` and create a list `matches`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I do not disagree with you but my answer breaks the loop once a keyword is detected in a sentence.

Comment: @AGNGazer honestly, it seems like you should just use `any`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a filtered new list based on your keyword search in a second list using `any`:

```
>>> [x for x in queries.split(',') if any(kw in x for kw in keywords)]
['watch movie online', ' movie poster', ' course of events', ' movie in this summer', ' python course', ' watch movie about training course']
```

The `break` is naturally in `any` since it will short-circuit on the first True and break out of the loop over `keywords`.

Then print the new list or sequence using `'\n'.join(iterable)` to get the effect of printing each element in the loop.

```
>>> print ('\n'.join(x for x in queries.split(',') if any(kw in x for kw in keywords)))
watch movie online
 movie poster
 course of events
 movie in this summer
 python course
 watch movie about training course
```

In that case, you can use a generator vs a list comprehension.

However, don't be afraid of just using a loop in Python; they are easy to understand and obvious in intent.

(And your can strip the space on the elements using `.lstrip(x)` if desired.)

Comment: @AGNGazer this code doesn't continue through `keywords` .. `any` short-circuits

Comment: not the downvote but you create an unnecessary list in '\n'.join(..) where you could use a generator instead (altough it might be in the spirit of the question)

Answer (score -1):

Use `itertools`:

```
import itertools
[x for x in queries.split(',')
 if len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda i: i not in x, keywords)))
    != len(keywords)]
```

Sorry for ugly indenting.

The above code stops checking the rest of the `keywords` once one match is detected.